# Reload fresh class data after calling the 'save' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am trying to refresh a database query result.

My data flow is the following:

```
Articles::UserRelationship.where(:user_id => user.id).count # Load data
@article.save
Articles::UserRelationship.where(:user_id => user.id).count # Load cached data
```

On the second time I load the `Articles::UserRelationship` I would like to not load cached data so that I can retrieve that refreshed.

**How can I do** since the above code load always cached data for the second statement?

P.S.: I tried to use the `reload` method but it seams don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can adjust ActiveRecord config to disable query cache:

API references is [on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/958b0e977a263100e3767d749afc08986acc4e7e/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb#L42)

try this out

```
Articles.uncached do
  Articles::UserRelationship.where(:user_id => user.id).count
end
```